# Changing Amplitude & Frequency of numpy.sin(wt) in pylab

Tags: python, plot, signals, matplotlib, trigonometry

For part of another project, I just need to make a simple sine wave with some frequency f.

Changing "samples" gives some strange effects on the pylab plot and I just don't know why!

using samples=500   gives a plot with  frequency = 1/50 Hz.

using samples=1000  gives a plot with  frequency = 1/100 Hz.

then with larger samples like 5000 and 10000, the plotted wave changes amplitude along the t axis, in patterns.

```
import numpy as N
f = 10.
w = 2. * N.pi * f
time_interval = 100
samples = 5000
t = N.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
y = N.sin(w * t)
pylab.plot(t, y)
pylab.show()
```

Any help here would be great! I just want a basic sine wave but can't even seem to do that!

Comment: The amplitude changing along the 't' axis is probably [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). When you zoom in on the plot of the larger samples, does the amplitude still look wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew - yes, when I zoom in the amplitude still isn't constant. I think it's something to do with the sampling rate compared to the frequency.  Possibly Nyquist theorem related now I've thought about it.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Please consider first your screens resolution with your `f` and `time_interval`. What did you expected to see? Did you tried to do what I suggested on my answer? Please note that your amplitude is constant 1. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a slight misconception with `samples`. It only gives the resolution of time. Try to plot with `time_interval= 1` and vary the `samples` (Start with small values like 10 and increase it then gradually). You'll see.

Answer (score 2):

To make eat's answer explicit, I set `time_interval` to 1, and varied `samples`, as he suggested:

```
import pylab
import numpy as N
f = 10.
w = 2. * N.pi * f
time_interval = 1
fig = pylab.figure()
for i, samples in enumerate((5, 50, 500, 5000)):
    pylab.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    pylab.title('%i samples'%samples)
    t = N.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
    y = N.sin(w * t)
    pylab.plot(t, y, '.-')
fig.show()
```

50 samples is clearly not enough for a `time_interval` of 1; This is why 5000 isn't enough samples for a `time_interval` of 100.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example.

```
import pylab 
x=pylab.arange(0,150,0.2)
y=pylab.sin(x);
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

Look closely at the data being created:

`x` is an array (technically datatype = numpy.ndarray) from 0 to 149.8 with an interval of 0.2, i.e. type x to see `array([0., 0.2, 0.4, ..., 149.8])`

`y` is an array from sin(0) to sin(149.8), i.e. `array([0., 0.198..., ...,  -0.839...])`

Answer (score 0):

From the given parameters: Frequency, F = 10 Hz, Time period, T = 100 s and Number of samples for T = 100 s, N = 5000.

This implies, the No. of cycles = F * T = 10 * 100 = 1000. Let choose T = 10/F, to visualize 10 cycles. This means that we will get 10 cycles from the 10 Hz sine wave in 1 sec. This also means that we will have 5000 samples for the 10 cycles, or 500 samples per cycle which is quite a bit for replication of the signal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

F = 10
T = 10/F
Fs = 5000
Ts = 1./Fs
N = int(T/Ts)

t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t)

plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.show()
```